# compare and extract number from string in jpql

Tags: jpql

I have column named `record_number` of type `varchar` that has the following format data: `[currentYear]-[Number]` `ex:2015-11`

I need to search for the maximum number of this column; ie: if the value of the column that holds the maximum is `2015-15` and then the value should be `15`, however if the column has a value of `2016-2`, then the max should be `2`.
how can I do it in jpql?

I'm using Postgres and EJB 3.1

Comment: I think I not understand what you want to do... Do you need to order the results by "desceding order" using the column `record_number` (with the logic that you explained) and get the first result, corrrect?

Comment: yes exactly, at the end, I want to get the column that has the max value according to the sort logic

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SUBSTRING](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userGuide/en-US/html/ch13.html#d5e2102) method of the JPA:

```
select table From Table table order by SUBSTRING(table.record_number, 5) desc;
```

To get only the first result, you need to use the method `maxResults`, like this:

```
em.createQuery("select table From Table table order by SUBSTRING(table.record_number, 5) desc")
    .setMaxResults(1) -- only the first result
    .getResultList()
```

Comment: Thank you Dherik for your answer, however the query doesn't work as expected because if I have 2015-10 and 2015-9, then the result is 2015-9 as substring compares strings and consider that `'9' `is greater than `'10'`

Comment: I forgot this string problem... If you can't update the `record_number` column for another format or create a new column on database with an appropriate date type, sadly, I think you don't have an alternative with JPA to resolve this problem. There is no JPA function to: format this varchar to a date before the `order by`, transform this varchar information from `2015-9` to `2015-09` before the `order by` or a "string to number" function. Note: you probably will have performance problems with a query manipulating the string before the `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem based on the comment of Dherik:
I used the following query to get the object that holds the correct value which seems more optimized than the one porposed by Dherik:

```
final TypedQuery<Table> query = createTypedQuery("from Table t where t.recordNumber= (select max(t.recordNumber) from t)", Table.class);
Table t= null;
    try {
        t = query.getSingleResult();
        }catch(Exception e){
         //handle Exception Here
        }
return t;
```

The trick is since it's my app which creates the record number, I changed the method that creates the record number to format the number on 2 digits to avoid having wrong string comparaison (the case when `'9'`  is considered greater than `'10'`)

```
// format the number <10 so that is on 2 digits
final String formattedNumber = String.format("%02d", number);
final int year = SomeUtilClass.getYearFromDate(new Date());
return new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-").append(formattedNumber).toString();
```